# Send email with EWS-office 365 (when Neither IMAP nor POP 3 are available)?

Tags: python, email, exchangewebservices

I would need to send email through outlook email id (no-reply email id). EWS is the only option -Neither IMAP nor POP 3 are available.

Has anyone done this, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if this O365, you should look into the Microsoft Graph API, since EWS will no longer work with Exchange O365 after October of 2020.  You can start [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph), just keep in mind that Graph does a whole lot more than just email.